# how to upload data using GPRS

Tags: c#, c, gsm, at-command, gprs

I have wavecom GSM/GPRS Modem. currently I use it as GSM only and send sms using AT commands then receive it as other end connected to computer. this computer program read sms then upload  to website. uploading to website is simple as calling url with querystring. like http://www.mtsonweb.com/fuel.php?p=$589,458,458,4$

Now the second part at server end is extra, Since we have GPRS modem we can use it to send data directly to website.

Website is on shared hosting and we can not make socket connections. Can we use AT commands to provide network apn and call weblink to push data directly to website?

Answer (score 0):

The basic procedure to use GPRS with a GSM/GPRS modem is to dial with a string like `ATDT*99***1#` or similar (check your device's documentation for the specific commands to setup the right APN, etc.) then pass off control to `pppd` or whatever software your OS uses for PPP, to establish a PPP link over the serial device.